# CMOS reset does not clear old boot options

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, boot, bios, motherboard

I'm trying to get rid of old boot options for Ubuntu on an Asus P8C WS motherboard.

I moved the jumper over to the reset pins and took out the CMOS battery and waited about 5 minutes before putting the battery back in and moving the jumper back.

I booted the server with all hard drives disconnected and got a message about restoring the BIOS, after pressing F1 I got into the BIOS and saw that the clock was reset but all the old Ubuntu boot options were still present and I couldn't seem to delete them from the interface.

This appears to be causing booting issues, I needed to disable all boot options in BIOS, then connect a usb live stick and restart the system to get it to boot. I can currently boot into the OS on the internal drive, but if I try to boot from the USB live stick, it will just hang on the BIOS splash screen and I can't get into the bios. The motherborad DIAG_HDD light comes on as well when the splash screen freezes. When I pull out the USB, it boots, but with ACPI errors.

All of this started after reinstalling Ubuntu, the issues started after restarting.

Any ideas what's going on?

My gut instinct is that I'll need to just update the BIOS (I'm using an older version), but I'm not too certain.

Comment: did you consult your mobo manual when determining the process for clearing CMOS? mine for instance requires initiating a POST from a cold shutdown, while the jumper is set. then you reboot. I'm not suggesting that that is what will work for your mobo, but that the process varies widely between manufacturers and even models. now what boot information are you trying to clear? generally, the most OS specific the boot options get is to indicate on what bus/disk/partition/volume the OS bootloader is at. beyond that, what are you trying to clear?

Comment: What Frank said. Also, do you know your USB boot stick is good? Systems freezing when booting to measure can indicate bad media. Recreate the stick or try a different one.

Comment: I followed the motherboard instruction manual steps. I did notice that it did not state you re-power the computer with the jumper moved, but I have seen other motherboards where that is required. I'm a bit wary of powering it on like that if the manual doesn't say so. The USB stick is a good stick too. It works fine on other machines. I'm trying to clear out UEFI boot options. They simply say 'ubuntu', there's like 16 of them too. I get the sense that they are stored on some kind of NVRAM if pulling the battery out didn't work (what Asus suggested). How long does volatile RAM hold a charge?

Comment: is it possible you are seeing the GRUB boot menu (the ubuntu boot loader)? a picture would help.